# Can Lambda Calculus be used to represent a Riemann sum?

Tags: riemann-sum, lambda-calculus

Lambda Calculus can be used to represent integers(Church encoding), booleans, binary operators, division, etc... but can it be used to represent a Riemann sum and how so? Can it represent all Riemann sums? Pi can be written as a Riemann sum so can Pi be represented in Lambda Calculus?

Comment: Since you’re essentially just building everything up inductively out of function composition, there’s no way you can construct uncountably many things, so as a tangentially-related issue I will point out that it is impossible to represent *all* real numbers. I think that should probably answer your questions about the encodability of *all* Riemann sums, though. However, there are *plenty* of real numbers that we can construct and represent, usually using Cauchy sequences, but they are still countable in number - and I suppose an analogous result probably holds for Riemann sums.

Comment: @JackCrawford

The wikipedia page on Church Encoding mentions:
"The data types and functions described above demonstrate that any data type or calculation may be encoded in lambda calculus. This is the Church-Turing thesis."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding

Are they failing to admit that irrational numbers are excluded from this process? Isn't Pi just a Riemann sum which is a calculation which therefore should be representable in Lambda Calculus? I just can't find any example of how this would be accomplished.

Comment: Plenty of irrational numbers are encodable; any algebraic number, for example. Even plenty of non-algebraic numbers, depending on how you set up your encoding. Just not *all* of them. Rather than talking about Riemann sums I’ll talk about Cauchy sequences; you can represent real numbers as either I suppose since the former is basically just a sum over the latter. For *practically* any particular number you can imagine, you can *probably* find some way to write down an algorithm that generates its corresponding Cauchy sequence, such as certain classic formulas for progressively approximating pi

Comment: ...but given that every algorithm for generating such a Cauchy sequence itself must be defined inductively, there’s just no way you can represent uncountably many things. You can encode any type — but the ‘type of real numbers’ is usually taken to be essentially noncomputable (that is, it doesn’t come with actual instances of every real number, it’s a sort of workaround for dealing with these uncountable infinities). It’s a weird beast. I recommend checking out an automated theorem proving language like Leanprover if you want to get more intuitions about how we can see the reals as a type.